# Error on mobil responsive facebook login nodejs passport nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have a problem, I am currently working with nodejs - passportjs and nginx.

In facebook login web version works fine,
The problem I have in the mobil version, I connect from my phone to enter with facebook and jumps a vet of nginx error

Saying that you set up an error screen in nginx.conf,

I'm trying to figure out what it can be? Someone happened to him

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The subject I had was not "NGINX" If someone happens to you, you must do it and log in to facebook and some users do not have "EMAIL" if there is no phone to enter, you must check if it exists or not, I had not fixed The "REGISTRATION ERROR"